# Trigger email when a new record is created in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have an automated process to create records in a DynamoDB table. I want to receive an email when a new records/object gets created. How can I do this?

I tried using Zapier and they have a bug in the DynamoDB Zap so it does not work

Comment: try having a lambda function which gets triggered by dynamodb stream. so whenever you insert a new record you will be able to send email using lambda function.

Answer (score 5):

From [DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html):

> Amazon DynamoDB is integrated with AWS Lambda so that you can create triggers—pieces of code that automatically respond to events in DynamoDB Streams. With triggers, you can build applications that react to data modifications in DynamoDB tables.
>
> If you enable DynamoDB Streams on a table, you can associate the stream ARN with a Lambda function that you write. Immediately after an item in the table is modified, a new record appears in the table's stream. AWS Lambda polls the stream and invokes your Lambda function synchronously when it detects new stream records.

So, you can:

- Configure DynamoDB to generate a **DynamoDB stream**
- Create an **AWS Lambda function** that is triggered by the stream
- Write code in the Lambda function that sends an email via **Amazon Simple Email Service (SES)**. Your code could filter the records so that you are only notified about specific updates of interest.

Actually, it can be a little complex to configure Amazon SES, so instead of "sending an email", I would recommend sending a message to **Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)**. You can then **subscribe email addresses** to the Amazon SNS topic. All subscribers will receive the notification via email (or SMS if you prefer!).